# Interact with linux server using java JSCH

Tags: java, linux, unix, ssh, jsch

I have created java program using *JSch* class. Program successfully execute the (`ls, cd, change`) commands. These commands dint need any inputs. But while executing the `/usr/ses/b/kr` command it require the *password*.

Can you please reply how I can send password to linux server using **JSch**. Or there is any another way?

```
((ChannelExec)channel).setCommand("/usr/ses/b/kr;");
```

Answer (score -1):

You should set StrictHostKeyChecking property "no" and channel should be set shell.as following.

```
    String username = "xxxyyyzzz";
    String password = "aaabbbccc";
    String host     = "192.168.1.1"; // sample ip address
    if(command.getText().toString() != ""){
        JSch jsch = new JSch();
        try {
            session = jsch.getSession(username, host, 22);
            session.setPassword(password);

            Properties properties = new Properties();
            properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
            session.setConfig(properties);
            session.connect(30000);

            channel = session.openChannel("shell");
            channel.setInputStream(bais);
            channel.setOutputStream(baos);
            channel.connect();

        } catch (JSchException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        }
    }
    else{
        //
    }
```

Comment: can you please tell data type of bais and also what should initial value of bais and baos variable.

Comment: it does not matter, you can use channel.setInputStream(System.in);
            channel.setOutputStream(System.out);
instead.

Comment: I have made changes as suggested.It doesnt display anything. I want to execute the command /usr/ses/b/kr; that take password as input. thanks for reply

Comment: I have used below code:session = jsch.getSession(userName, host, 22);
                 session.setPassword(password);

                 Properties properties = new Properties();
                 properties.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
                 session.setConfig(properties);
                 session.connect(30000);

                 channel = session.openChannel("shell");
                
                 channel.connect();
                 System.out.println("Connected");
                 channel.setInputStream(System.in);
                 channel.setOutputStream(System.out);